# Использование материализованных журналов

Tags: база-данных, oracle, инспекция-кода

В базе есть три таблицы

1. Точки. Точка может иметь три статуса (0, 1, 2)
2. Кластеры
3. И кросстаблица точки-кластеры

Нужно для каждого кластера собрать статистику, сколько в нем точек определенного статуса.

Для этого было создано материализованное представление

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MVW_CLUSTER_STAT 
LOGGING 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS NO INMEMORY NOCACHE NOPARALLEL USING INDEX
REFRESH ON DEMAND 
FORCE 
USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT 
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE AS 
SELECT
  pvt.ID,
  pvt.UNDEF,
  pvt.DETECT,
  pvt.MSM
FROM (
  SELECT
    cls.ID,
    cp.STATUS,
    COUNT(cp.ID) AS CNT
  FROM
    clusters cls
    JOIN station_clusters PARTITION(lic) stn_cls ON (
      cls.ID = stn_cls.CLUSTER_ID
    )
    JOIN control_points cp ON (
      cp.STN_ID = stn_cls.STN_ID AND
      cp.STN_SYS_ID = stn_cls.STN_SYS_ID
    )
  GROUP BY
    cls.ID,
    cp.STATUS
) PIVOT (
  SUM(CNT)
  FOR STATUS IN (0 AS "UNDEF", 1 AS "DETECT", 2 AS "MSM")
) pvt;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_MVW_CLUSTER_STAT_CLUSTER_ID ON MVW_CLUSTER_STAT (ID ASC);
```

Также были созданы журналы

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON CLUSTERS
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 30 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING
  WITH PRIMARY KEY,
  ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "STATION_CLUSTERS"
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 30 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING
  WITH PRIMARY KEY,
  ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "CONTROL_POINTS"
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 30 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING
  WITH PRIMARY KEY,
  ROWID ("STATUS", "STN_ID", "STN_SYS_ID") INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

В программу приходят пакеты обновления статуса точки. В одном пакете ~10-20 обновлений. После импорта всего пакета вызывается процедура обновления представления

```java
try (Statement refreshStmt = connection.createStatement()) {
    refreshStmt.execute("BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('mvw_cluster_stat'); END;");
}
```

Смущает, что каждое обновление выполняется 500-1500 мс (в среднем 700). Так и должно быть или я где-то накосячил с журналами?

На всякий случай, план исходного запроса

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name             | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                  | 27822 |   842K|       |  1448   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY PIVOT           |                  | 27822 |   842K|       |  1448   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                         |                  | 59020 |  1786K|       |  1448   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY               |                  | 59020 |  1498K|       |  1448   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS               |                  | 59020 |  1498K|       |  1448   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   5 |      VIEW                      | VW_GBF_18        | 59020 |  1210K|       |  1437   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   6 |       HASH GROUP BY            |                  | 59020 |  1440K|    12M|  1437   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  7 |        HASH JOIN               |                  |   357K|  8729K|       |   227   (5)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   8 |         PART JOIN FILTER CREATE| :BF0000          | 30809 |   361K|       |    56   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   9 |          PARTITION LIST ALL    |                  | 30809 |   361K|       |    56   (2)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     2 |
|  10 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL    | CONTROL_POINTS   | 30809 |   361K|       |    56   (2)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     2 |
|  11 |         PARTITION LIST SINGLE  |                  |   228K|  2896K|       |   167   (3)| 00:00:01 |KEY(AP)|KEY(AP)|
|  12 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL     | STATION_CLUSTERS |   228K|  2896K|       |   167   (3)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
|* 13 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_CLUSTERS      |     1 |     5 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

---------------------------------------------------

   7 - access("CP"."STN_SYS_ID"="STN_CLS"."STN_SYS_ID" AND "CP"."STN_ID"="STN_CLS"."STN_ID")
  13 - access("CLS"."ID"="ITEM_1")
```

Comment: @0xdb этот вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к SQL запросам и имеет отношение к дизайну БД. Все метки выставлены корректно

Comment: К дизайну БД никакого отношения, это имплементация БД, посмотрите описание меток. Ну вы автор, и вам решать.

Comment: +1 к @0xdb метка sql актуальна хотя бы потому, что в вопросе написан sql. А во вторых, так она привлечет тех, кто подписан на sql, но не подписан на oracle